# How to define type to choose one but not another - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript2.0, react-typescript

I would like to define the type so that TS knows that when I define one variable, another will be undefined

```ts
interface Fruits { 
    apple: string,
    strawberry: string 
}
            
type ExtraFruits = Fruits & ({
    banana: string;
    kiwi: undefined;
} | {
    kiwi: string;
    banana: undefined;
})
```

and when I'm using ExtraFruits interface like this:

```ts
const {apple, strawberry, kiwi, banana} = fruits <--- fruit is ExtraFruits type
    
const selectedFruit = kiwi ?  kiwi :  banana
```

TS think that kiwi is possibily undefined but in this configuration it is not

Comment: What's `fruit` value? Your example works fine for me in [TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/WyvEKw).

Comment: fruit value can be _{ apple: "a",strawberry:"b", banana:"c", kiwi: undefined }_ or  _{ apple: "a",strawberry:"b", banana: undefined, kiwi:"c" }_ . If you hover the mouse over the **banana** variable in line 16 you will see that it has the type string | undefined and with this condition it should be string

Comment: Ah, my bad, I see what you mean now. While there's a huge push into this direction (of conditional type narrowing) coming into 4.4.0 with [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730), this particular case of 'type alternation' is not covered - yet.

Comment: `selectedFruit` can in fact be `undefined`; see [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQAZvw).  You should consider editing the code here to be `const selectedFruit = kiwi !== undefined ? kiwi : banana` or even `const selectedFruit = kiwi ?? banana` which will actually have the problem you're asking about (where `selectedFruit` is seen as `string | undefined` but can only be `string`)

Comment: I think problem in destructing object. TypeScript not handle contention between property of destructed object.

for `const selectedFruit = fruits.kiwi ? fruits.kiwi : fruits.banana;` all works.